# Set paths for PHP includes on localhost

Tags: php, path, include

My new ecom project is in the ecom folder on my mac located here:
"Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ecom"

I access it in the browser by typing localhost/ecom

Problem:
My script fails when I want to include a file, like this:
    require('/includes/header.html');

It works when I write it like this:
    require('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ecom/includes/header.html');

Is there a PHP function I can use to change a setting so that the top version works? Keeping in mind that I have other projects, localhost/wiki, localhost/social that should work in a similar manner.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should ise relative pathes.

`/` means the directory beside of `/Application`

`includes/header.html` (without the startin /) means the folder relative to my current position. Normally beside the `index.php`

Answer (score 1):

> require('/includes/header.html');

This is an absolute path. If you want to include a PHP file with a path relative to your current file and you don't know or don't care about the full path, use a relative path that does *not* begin with a `/`.

Assuming your PHP file is located in `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ecom` and header.html is located in `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ecom/includes` then you need the following code:

```
 require('includes/header.html');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the simple idea use in Joomla / Wordpress / Cakephp & other open source.

Use:

require( dirname( __ FILE __ ).'/includes/header.php');

Let me know if this works.

Thanks,
Munjal